# Does [Serializable] work for inherited classes?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, appdomain

I haven't worked much with remoting so excuse this rather rudimentary question, If I derive a class from an abstract class marked as [Serializable] (for passing the data across an appdomain), does the other side get the actual overriden implementation? ie does polymorphism work over remoting/Serializable?

I need to create a clone on the other side rather than operating on the original so MarshalByRef is not an option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes when you deserialize a type, the same type is reconstituted in the remote domain.

You can control the deserialized type by using the IObjectReference pattern:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iobjectreference.aspx

Comment: How does that work? I mean I would understand how Serializable works if it simply instantiates the same type on the other side and copies all the data with it, but if I have some abstract class say  BirdBase and the other side inherits and passes a Bird : BirdBase it would have to send the actual code.. isn't that a security concern as well?

Comment: Both sides must be able to access the serialized type, and all that it contains. The deserializer will attempt to load the final type of the object that was serialized. If it fails, an exception is thrown.

Comment: Well that doesn't work then :/ one side knows only of the base class and the other overrides it

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to see that  [Serializable] is not inherited is press F12 and see "Inherited = false" in AttributeUsage. The harder option is to RTFM at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcfsa90a.aspx .

Essentially you need to mark all you classes as serializable and they will be deserialized properly.

Comment: You must also apply the [Serializable] attribute to all base classes or the Remoting proxy will throw the exception "Type in assembly is not marked as serializable".